# Writing an eCAP plugin for Squid: How to link OpenSSL and other libraries

Tags: libraries, openssl, c++, squid, shared-libraries

I'm writing an eCAP adapter (in C++) for Squid. I've seen that libtool is required in order to create a library and import it into Squid.

I started from the adapter_modifying example (that can be found here http://www.measurement-factory.com/tmp/ecap/ecap_adapter_sample-0.2.0.tar.gz) and added some features (encryption of JSON objects).

In order to do so, I'm using this library https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/ and this OpenSSL wrapper https://github.com/shanet/Crypto-Example

After compiling and installing the adapter (it involves the creation of a library with libtool), I've run squid but the adapter crashes as soon as I instanciate an object of the OpenSSL wrapper.

My plugin stops running as soon as I instantiate the Crypto wrapper:

```
Crypto crypto;
```

If I don't execute the adaptation method and just buffer and forward the chunks, everything works fine. Do you see anything in the code of this library https://github.com/shanet/Crypto-Example that may cause this issue?

Do you know how I can access the error log (or standard error) of my plugin?

How can I correctly link these two libraries to my adapter? Which commands should I execute?